# how to write query using example?

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

There is a Example Object in hibernate criterion to use as query from a example object like:

```
Cat cat = new Cat();  
cat.setSex('F');  
cat.setColor(Color.BLACK);  
List results = session.createCriteria(Cat.class)  
    .add( Example.create(cat) )  
    .list();
```

but in spring-boot-jpa, Is there any way I can use that? If so How?

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your explanation, I understood that you are trying to find a Black, Femlae cat. In that cas In your repository class write a method like this

```
findBySexAndColour(Character sex, String Colour)
```

change the type of sex to String if that is the datatype you are using

Answer (score 0):

You can always write a [custom implementation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations) where you inject your dependencies and basically do whatever you want including using literally your code.

pvpkiran already explained how you can create the exact example query using a specifically named method.

If you want to construct a query dynamically [`Specification`s](https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/) might be useful.